# Consul within Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, consul, spring-cloud-consul

Has anyone been able to use Consul within Docker Swarm successfully? The reason I ask is that I've been struggling for days to get it running ([my additional post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220374/consul-on-docker-swarm-with-spring-boot-clients)).

The only way I can get Consul to start is to run it using "network_mode: host" and then I have the issue that the HealthCheck URLs registered with it by the Spring Boot apps use the internal network address of the container meaning that Consul cannot mark the container as healthy as it cannot access the internal IP from outside of the swarm.

I have seen other posts where people have abandoned the use of Consul in favour of native Swarm discovery, but we are also making use of the Consul KV functionality as well as HAproxy/consul-template for load-balancing requests into the stack.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how best to proceed?